# unexpected behavior of object pushed in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I've made a script which creates an object in a foreach loop, the object gets filled with information and then goes in a nested foreach loop adding even more information.

The script is to make an overview of information, posts by user + some other information

```
$data = array();

foreach ($users as $user)
{
    $row = new stdClass();

    $row->user = $user;
    $row->name = fullname($user);

    $posts = getPosts($user);

    foreach ($posts as $post)
    {
        $row->title = $post->title;
        $row->datetime = $post->date;

        $row->views = getViews($post->id);

        $data[] = $row;
    }
}
```

When the script is done all "rows" in `$data` are the same per user, all showing the last added row for that user.
When I check the row before putting it in the array, it's the information I expect, it seems the object is still actively used although I've put it in an array.

Should I close the object before putting it in an array or something else?

Thanks in advance!

**=EDIT=**

`$data[] = $row;` is in the right spot because I want the output to be like this:

```
Emma  | 'My first post!' | 22-10-2014 | 8
Emma  | 'posting again!' | 23-10-2014 | 24
Emma  | 'Back from ...'  | 02-01-2014 | 69
Rick  | 'youknowit'      | 10-10-2013 | 45
Freud | 'Yo momma'       | 01-01-1970 | 123
Frued | 'fruitsalad'     | 02-02-2010 | 3
```

Comment: What do you mean by "close the object" ?

Comment: Are you sure you that `$data[] = $row;` is on the right spot?
Shouldn't it be outside of the $posts foreach loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Update**] Your code makes a lot more sense with the new information added to the question :) And the solution gets far more easy : Simply [**`clone`**](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.clone.php) `$row` in each `$post`-loop .

```php
foreach ($users as $user)
{
    $row = new stdClass();

    $row->user = $user;
    $row->name = fullname($user);

    $posts = getPosts($user);

    foreach ($posts as $post)
    {
        $item = clone $row; //<-- clone $row, $data will end up as you desire

        $item->title = $post->title;
        $item->datetime = $post->date;
        $item->views = getViews($post->id);

        $data[] = $item;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution makes a posts array within the row object, although this is a nicer/better way, I need all information in one object. The information eventually goes into an excel and I need all information on each row/line, I have no control over the script that generates the excel, it expects an array of objects, each object containing all information.

Comment: @seloh77 OK, now I understand why your code was as it was! It was not so clear without the explanation of desired output :) see updated answer.